# Jenkins version doesn't match

Tags: jenkins

I have jenkins installed on an Ubuntu VM.

In the web interface I can see the version is

```
2.32.3.
```

However, if I go to `/home/bitnami/.jenkins/config.xml` I see the version is `1.0` (there is this tag: `<version>1.0</version>`)

How can it be? am I looking in the wrong place?

Thanks

Comment: Did you search in other  .jenkins folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have two versions installed, one in your system and one in your user account.
Did you installed by `apt-get` or `wget`?

When you execute the app, you may be running the Jenkins installed in your system and you are looking in your user HOME directory
Try (`whereis jenkins` and `which jenkins`) and execute this `jenkins` in your terminal to see if the version match.

Comment: Ok I really had a mess on the server, I found the "real" installation under `/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home`